# Rsync: Is there any way to exclude multiples files and directory shortly?

Tags: linux, rsync

Is there any way to exclude multiples files and directory shortly with rsync?

Below is my code:

```
rsync -avzh . blabla@blabla:~/ --exclude=__pycache__ --exclude=checkpoints --exclude=logs --exclude=.git --exclude=plot
```

I have to explicitly declare for each file (dir). I feel it too long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for `rsync` (see `man rsync`) has the `--exclude-from` parameter that will allow you to specify a list of exclusions in a file.

With regard to your set of example exclusions, the directories should be followed with `/` to show they are directories rather than unspecified files or directories, and those that are only in your home directory itself should be prefixed with `/` so that they don't match anywhere else.

In an exclusions file they could be listed like this

```
# Directories found anywhere
__pycache__/
checkpoints/
logs/
plot/

# Directories found only in HOME
/.git/
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `bash`, you could use a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) which expands to multiple `--exclude=xxx` options:

```
rsync -avzh --exclude={__pycache__,checkpoints,logs,.git,plot} . blabla@blabla:~/
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you can formulate a pattern that would match all possible directories/files that you'd like to exclude, the only other way I can think of is to read the patterns from a file with `--exclude-from=filename`.

You could also store the patterns in an array (in a shell that supports this, such as `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh`, or `yash`), which may be useful if you're writing a script:

```bash
exclude=( __pycache__ checkpoints logs .git plot )

for pattern in "${exclude[@]}"; do
    exclude=( "${exclude[@]:1}" --exclude="$pattern" )
done

rsync --archive --verbose --compress --human-readable \
    "${exclude[@]}" \
    . blabla@blabla:
```

Or use the positional parameters (less typing, and portable to all POSIX shells):

```sh
set -- __pycache__ checkpoints logs .git plot

for pattern do
    set -- "$@" --exclude="$pattern"
    shift
done

rsync --archive --verbose --compress --human-readable \
    "$@" \
    . blabla@blabla:
```

Comment: Perhaps a caveat about having a *very* long list (IE args limits)?

Comment: @bxm If you have _many thousands_ of patterns for things to exclude, you should probably use `--exclude-from` to read them from file.  That would be, I think, a quite unusual situation though, but the code in the answer could easily be modified to write the patterns to a file that is used with `--exclude-from`.